# How to overwrite LWC template CSS

Tags: lightning-web-components, style, template

I have a LWC component with a table and want to make each row formatted as currency. I know with HTML we can use the `format-style="currency"` but I think the template is overwriting this styling because it is not working. Is it possible to overwrite with something like !important or another way?

```
<tr>
   <template for:each={colDATA.SummaryMonths} for:item="month">
      <td format-style="currency" key={month}>
         ${month.Column9}
     </td>
   </template>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format-style` is an attribute of [`lightning-formatted-number`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/specification) not of `td`:

> The number formatting style to use. Possible values are decimal, **currency**,
> percent, and percent-fixed. This value defaults to decimal.

Indeed you should use that component to format a number as currency:

```html
<tr>
    <template for:each={colDATA.SummaryMonths} for:item="month">
        <td key={month}>
            <lightning-formatted-number value={month.Column9} format-style="currency" currency-code="USD"></lightning-formatted-number>
        </td>
    </template>
</tr>
```